# How to obtain multiple different values from the same key name in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that is the match list of recent games played. Let's say this dictionary (match list) is stored in the variable `m`. Here's the contents:

```
{
"matches": [
    {
        "platformId": "NA1",
        "gameId": 3000208798,
        "champion": 7,
        "queue": 420,
        "season": 13,
        "timestamp": 1552770736282,
        "role": "SOLO",
        "lane": "MID"
    },
    {
        "platformId": "NA1",
        "gameId": 3000221890,
        "champion": 2,
        "queue": 420,
        "season": 13,
        "timestamp": 1552768857241,
        "role": "NONE",
        "lane": "JUNGLE"
    },
    {
        "platformId": "NA1",
        "gameId": 2999711945,
        "champion": 72,
        "queue": 420,
        "season": 13,
        "timestamp": 1552722174457,
        "role": "NONE",
        "lane": "JUNGLE"
    },
    {
        "platformId": "NA1",
        "gameId": 2999696777,
        "champion": 60,
        "queue": 420,
        "season": 13,
        "timestamp": 1552720181393,
        "role": "NONE",
        "lane": "JUNGLE"
    },
    {
        "platformId": "NA1",
        "gameId": 2999691752,
        "champion": 7,
        "queue": 420,
        "season": 13,
        "timestamp": 1552718383760,
        "role": "SOLO",
        "lane": "MID"
    }
],
"startIndex": 0,
"endIndex": 5,
"totalGames": 66
}
```

The match list contains 5 matches or games, and I have been trying to write a function that gets all 5 `gameId`s and returns them in the form of a `list`.

I tried something like:

```
def getGameIds():
    gameIds = []
    for "gameId" in m:
        gameIds.append(m.get("gameId"))
    return gameIds
```

Thinking that I could loop through each occurrence of the key `"gameId"`, but I have not had any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try iterating over each entry adding to a new list:

```
l = [i['gameId'] for i in data['matches']]
# [i.get('gameId') for i in data['matches']] also works
```

Should produce list `l` containing:

```
[3000208798, 3000221890, 2999711945, 2999696777, 2999691752]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, this worked. I realized I didn't think to reference the second level dictionary, which should have been obvious considering the original dictionary is nested.

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but not quite there. Think about every element you need to access: a dictionary, then a list, then a dictionary. Try this instead:

```
def getGameIds():
    gameIds = []
    for subdict in m["matches"]:
        gameIds.append(subdict.get("gameId"))
    return gameIds
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I really was close, I just didn't think to reference the second level dictionary, which should have been obvious considering it's nested. I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [v for k,v in m.items() if k == "matches"]
glist = [i['gameId'] for d in l for i in d]
```